# jQuery carousel plugin, cycle2, not working in joomla 2.5 website

Tags: joomla, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to set up the jquery carousel plugin, cycle2, in joomla 2.5. I want a straightforward responsive carousel which will autostart and just run thru a series of pics on a loop on the introductory page in a joomla base website. I tried cycle2 out in a single page localhost website and it works well. But in joomla, it's not working. I've installed the 3 js files, jquery.cycle2.js, jquery.cycle2.tile.js and carousel.js in the template javascript folder and listed them in the template index.php folder, as I have done with a lot of other jquery code which running without any problems, so I'm puzzled as to why cycle2 doesn't work. Also, firebug shows that the cycle2 js files are not being loaded. I can't figure out why this is so. This is the html segment from the joomla page:

```
<div id="carousel">
 <div class="cycle-slideshow responsive" data-cycle-timeout = "3500" data-cycle-speed = "1000 data-cycle-fx="tileBlind" data-cycle-tile-count=17> 
  <img src="/templates/beez_20/images/carousel/siti_rs_1.png" >
  <img src="/templates/beez_20/images/carousel/siti_rs_2.png" >
  <img src="/templates/beez_20/images/carousel/siti_rs_3.png" >
  <img src="/templates/beez_20/images/carousel/siti_rs_4.png" >
  <img src="/templates/beez_20/images/carousel/siti_rs_5.png" >          
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: For something so simply, have you checked the Joomla Extensions Directory? For example, you can use [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/22409) or [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow/21300) If you don't want to use an extension (even though you should rather than editing your template), then can you please provide the code you're using to import your 3 JS files?

Comment: Thanks for the links, however I would prefer to go with cycle2. I placed the 3 files in the template javascript folder and inserted the following into the template index.php file - $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/javascript/jquery.cycle2.js', 'text/javascript'); - varying the name for each of the 3 js files. I have done this with several other jquery files and it has worked.

Comment: Ok and are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: The 5 images in the carousel are loaded in a vertical column in the page whereas they should, of course, be confined to the carousel.

Comment: I know they should be loaded into the carousel, but are you getting any errors on the browser console? This step 1 of debugging Javascript. Maybe if you were to provide a link to your site, it might help a little

Comment: I've been developing locally but I can upload the files to the server where you can have a look at the site. I'll get back as soon as I'm done :)

Comment: OK, the link is www.english2theworld.com and the carousel is on the home page, thanks for you help

Comment: Can you please disable the JCH plugin which is caching the JS files. It's extremely hard to debug with it turned on. Once done, also clear your cache in the Joomla Backend. This might also be the cause of the problem as there have been known to be some bugs when caching JS files